# SLIDESJS chrome bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome

I have a problem with SlidesJS plugin in my wordpress [theme](http://themes.pixlito.com/Simplio/gallery-post/).

Gallery is working but when the page load in the chrome it doesnt show the first slide correctly but next slide is okay. It works properly in FF, Opera and even IE 8. Sometimes it loads correctly but most of the time it doesnt.

If anyone knows a solution please help me. Thank you.

### jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#gallery-68").slides({
    pagination: true,
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: "http://themes.pixlito.com/Simplio/wp-content/themes/Simplio/images/ajax-loader.gif",
    generatePagination: true,
    crossfade: true,
    effect: "fade",
    bigTarget: true,
    hoverPause: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    play: 10000
   });
});
```

Comment: If you relay think that this is a chrome bug please report it [here](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. Problem was that I didn't specify width and height in the "img" tag.